# Winforms TextBox number presentation

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want the TextBox to display numbers with 3 digits and exponentials.

f.e. 0.123E-08

Is there a Way to do this with normal Winforms TextBoxes?

Comment: No, you will need to format it yourself for a TextBox using double.ToString() or string.Format()

Comment: Do you really want `0.123E-08`? Normally it would be normalised to `1.23E-09`

Comment: oh that was my mistake, of course 1.23E-09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) to format the string before setting `TextBox.Text`.

For example:

```
double value = 0.00000000123;

string s = value.ToString("#.###E00");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Or just assign to TextBox.Text:

```
textBox.Text = value.ToString("#.###E00");;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I now there is not a native property on Textbox but you can apply the instructions on the links below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString